# Specify the author in a mediawiki page

Tags: wiki, mediawiki

I downloaded mediawiki wiki to develop my project and I want to include the ability to add the author of an article within the mediawiki page : The only extension I've found is this : www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AuthorInfo ,it adds that users have contributed according to edits, where you have to add this text to the page where you want to show the list of authors :

```
<AuthorInfo limit="4"></AuthorInfo>
```

but if I wanted to let the user who writes an article to add your name to in article, example;

```
Name Article
.
. 
.
.
written by XXX
```

Thanks you!!!

Comment: You could just add `* Written by ~~~.` at the bottom of the page.  Or do you want to automate that?  Or something else?

Comment: which button on the page? if there is a way to do it automatically would be even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the built-in configuration option [$wgMaxCredits](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgMaxCredits) and extensions like http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContributionCredits, which both use the article history to build and display a list of contributors automatically.